# Composing two functions in R gives different result than a new function enclosing both

Tags: r, precision, function-composition

I tried to look at the logistic map

```
logMap <- function(x){
r <- 0.5
4*r*x*(1-x)}
```

and its compositions such as:

```
logMap2_a <- function(x){
  logMap(logMap(x))}
```

Of course, you can also directly write a new function that composes logMap with itself:

```
logMap2 <- function(x){
r <- 0.5
16*r*r*x*(1-x)*(1-16*r*r*x*(1-x))}
```

Now, plotting the two things does not show the same curve:

```
curve(logMap2, from=0, to=1)
curve(logMap2_a, from=0, to=1)
```

The first figure shows the result of logMap2, the second that of logMap2_a.

[image: This is the picture I wanted to have, the power of two of the logistic map (function logMap2)]

[image: This is the curve of the composition which should yield the same curve as the power of two of the logistic map (function logMap2_a)]

My first idea was that the problem arises due to the precision of returned data, but I cannot imagine that this is a problem with this reasonably large numbers. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Your algebra is a bit off on the direct composition. I suggest you try it again.

Comment: Thanks, stupid me. Flagged the question for deletion. Sorry to have wasted your time!

Answer (score 1):

```
logMap2 <- function(x){
r <- 0.5
16*r*r*x*(1-x)*(1-4*r*x*(1-x))}
```